# delete folders and files from sourcefoge svn

Tags: svn, sourceforge

I have this project 
https://sourceforge.net/p/silvercsharp/code-0/HEAD/tree/
and I want to keep just the trunk,tags and branches directories
How can I do that ?

Comment: Do you want to remove the data from repository **history**?

Comment: I don't want to see the directory silvercsharp-code-0 and directory Silver when I open the link

Comment: Did my answer help you in 2013? Please, upvote and accept it then. :)

Answer (score 0):

- Read [**SVNBook**](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/index.html),
- The following [**chapter**](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.cycle.html) will help.

`svn delete http://svn.code.sf.net/p/silvercsharp/code-0/Silver/ http://svn.code.sf.net/p/silvercsharp/code-0/silvercsharp-code-0/ -m "Removed unnecessary folders"`

Make sure that you enter correct credentials and you have Read / Write access to the repository.

Comment: svn: E175013: Access to '/p/silvercsharp/code-0/!svn/me' forbidden

Comment: You don't have Read / Write access to the path / repository. Make sure you have Read / Write access on the repo and enter correct credentials.